# Minimize 12 lines of jquery in one

Tags: jquery

I have this lines of jquery:

```
$( "#flt21_BD2015" ).click(function() {
    $('#flt9_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt10_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt11_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt12_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt13_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt14_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt15_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt16_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt17_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt18_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt19_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();    
    $('#flt20_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
});
```

and

```
$( "#flt34_BD2015" ).click(function() {
    $('#flt22_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt23_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt24_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt25_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt26_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt27_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt28_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt29_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt30_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt31_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
    $('#flt32_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();    
    $('#flt33_BD2015').closest( "td" ).toggle();
});
```

Is posible to minimize that? Something like...

Make this from `#flt9_BD2015` to `#flt20_BD2015`.

and the same with the other:

Make this from `#flt22_BD2015` to `#flt33_BD2015`.

Comment: And what HTML is that supposed to work with? What, precisely, are you trying to do? Where did you get stuck when you attempted your own solution? Did you read, or even look at, the [jQuery API documentatioon](http://api.jquery.com/)? Questions about improving working code, typically (but apparently not always), belong on [codereview.se]. Also, why are those blocks in curly braces (`{` and `}`), is it a function, an Object, an `if`/`else` block?

Comment: You could probably use a regex on each tag inside of a div if the id or name matched a pattern... like flt\d{1,4}_BD20\d{2}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the ID attribute "ends with" selector:

```
$("[id$='_BD2015']").closest( "td" ).toggle();
```

Now that will select ALL of them so you need what (appears) to be a specific count of items from that list.  This then becomes HIGHLY dependent on the length :(

```
$("[id$='_BD2015']").closest( "td" ).slice(0,12).toggle();
```

IF you need the "rest" of them you can then do the NEXT 12 or ALL the rest:  This starts to get quite ugly as you can see.

```
$("[id$='_BD2015']").closest( "td" ).slice(13,12).toggle();

$("[id$='_BD2015']").closest("td").slice(0,12).last().nextAll().toggle();
```

NOTE: This is a prime case for a class selector instead

**EDIT:** with your added question clarification (click handler) you can somewhat simplify this:

```
$( "#flt21_BD2015" ).click(function() {
    $(this).closest("td").prevAll().toggle():
});
```

NOTE: this **MIGHT NOT WORK depending upon just what the ID targets** - something in some table but you will need to provide some HTML or some indication of what the structure looks like to better handle this.

If NONE of these work properly given that we have no idea the actual structure use @richessler suggestion (include all the ID's) OR add the class as I suggest here. `<td class="tdclassfirst">`

Comment: I used your first form an works awesome!! 
`$("[id$='_BD2015']").closest( "td" ).slice(9,21).toggle();` AND
`$("[id$='_BD2015']").closest( "td" ).slice(22,34).toggle();`

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#flt22_BD2015, #flt23_BD2015, #flt24_BD2015,...').closest("td").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jquery `$=` selector that will select all elements ending exactly with `_BD2015` :

```
$('[id$="_BD2015"]').closest( "td" ).toggle();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose your desired [JQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

And do something like this if it fits with the rest of your DOM elements:

```
$('[id$=BD2015]').closest('td').toggle();
```

As the documentation says ***$=*** :

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value ending
> exactly with a given string. The comparison is case sensitive.

So it will take all elements with id's ending with ***_BD2015***. But you can use other selectors if you want, that's just an example.